# Solve large noisy polynomial equation stably and efficiently

Tags: algorithm, performance, computational-geometry, polynomial-math, large-data

Assume we are given a polynomial system of equations

f_1(X_1,...,X_k)=0

...

f_n(X_1,...,X_k)=0,

where k<1000 and n ~ 20000. Here the parameters of the polynomial equations are assumed to be noisy, hence since the system is overdetermined we cannot expect to find a single solution (X_1,...,X_k). 
I am now looking for an efficient algorithm (or perhaps already implementation, ideally in R), with which I can solve such noisy polynomial systems of the above dimensions.

Comment: Can you tell more about the shape of the polynomials ? How they are built ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to find the minimum of the single polynomial f_1()^2 + f_2()^2 + .... f_n()^2. Because of the squarings, it will be small only when each individual f_i() is near zero. If the noise could be modelled such that the error obtained when computing f_i() was normally distributed and with the same variance for all f_i() this would also have good statistical properties.

Unfortunately, you say the error is in the parameters of the polynomials. Suppose for the moment that you are given X_i and you need to find the errors in the coefficients of the polynomials. You do this by finding small corrections to each coefficient of the polynomial which make the answer come out to zero, choosing the corrections to minimise their squared sum. You can do this separately for each polynomial. Because X_i are known, this amounts to minimising the sum of the squares of the corrections, subject to the constraint that a linear function in the corrections provides a value just large enough to make the polynomial produce zero. I think that you can solve this using Lagrange multipliers, and that if you do this, and take the solution and look at what the sum of the squares of the corrections is at this solution, the answer you get back is the square of the constraint on the linear function, divided by the sum of the squares of the coefficients of the linear constraints, which in this case arise from the value of the assumed X_i.

If you now take this function and attempt to minimise it by choosing X_i you are minimising a sum of rational functions, one for each f_i(). If the f_i() all have similar form then the the divisors will all be the same, which may make this less horrible. Perhaps you can find the minimum of this using a packaged numerical minimiser. One possible starting point would be the solution of the simpler problem I mentioned in the first paragraph - the minimum of f_1()^2 + f_2()^2 + ...

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. The idea to minimize f_1()^2 + f_2()^2 + .... f_n()^2 sounds very promising. Unfortunately, I was unable to understand your further outlines, so I would be very thankful I you could explain them briefly in a more concrete fashion, perhaps at some toy example.

Comment: Also do you have an idea what would be the best algorithm to find the minimum of f_1()^2 + f_2()^2 + .... f_n()^2 ? Is there some proper implementation?

Comment: There are numerical routines for minimization, and in fact numerical routines specifically for least squares minimization, such as https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/leastsquares.html